# ASP.Net - Function output shown before function called

Tags: asp.net

I have the following line of code in ASP.Net (VB)

```
Response.Write("<td class=""tblRow""><strong>" & ITServiceRow.NAME & " </strong><br>" & funcRAGColour(ITServiceRow.RAGSTATUS) & Environment.NewLine)
```

This should output the Name from *ITServiceRow.NAME* followed by the result of the function *funcRAGColour*.

However this is not the case. ASP.Net is outputting the value of the function *funcRAGColour*. first followed by the value of *ITServiceRow.NAME*.

Just trying to understand why this might be happening? If I replace the function with static text it executes fine, but when I put the function in it outputs the function result immediately before the name.

[image]

The image here, in yellow shows the full output that comes from the function, it is shown before everything else?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using String.Format instead to guarantee placement.

```
Response.Write(string.Format("<td class=""tblRow""><strong>{0}</strong><br />{1}{2}</td>",funcRAGColour(ITServiceRow.RAGSTATUS),Environment.NewLine))
```

Always do whatever you can to avoid string concatenation. String concatenation is tough on a system and uses much more memory and resources to be garbage collected than you think because it's actually far more complicated. String.Format and StringBuilder help get around this.

I am very suspect of the function funcRAGColour() itself though and think that is the problem. My guess is the function is not returning the output as a string, but instead is using Response.Write() to output it's result. That would cause it's value to appear first since it is called while the string is being assembled.

Keep in mind, Response.Write is NOT the way to do things in ASP.Net. It was need in classic ASP, but ASP.Net has HtmlTextWriters that can be used during the rendering process, controls for result placement, etc.. It's the old school, non object-oriented way of doing things that can get into trouble.